# LinkedList push() method in JavaScript with a tail

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I try to understand how `push()` method works with the use of tails in JS. here is the code:

```
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.next = null;
    }
  }
  class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
      this.length = 0;
      this.head = null;
      this.tail = null;
    }
    push(val) {
      const newNode = new Node(val)
      if (this.head===null) { // happens only once
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = this.head;
      } else {
        this.tail.next = newNode;   // this.a.next = b node???
        this.tail = newNode;
      }
      this.length++
    }
```

specifically, I don't understand the `else` part inside the `push()` method. How does each `next` of a `head` gets assigned a new node if we say `this.tail.next = newNode`? Where is the relation between head and tail and how by saying `this.tail.next = newNode` we get access to the `head` property of the list? When I run this code, it works perfectly correct and it confuses me.

```
const myList = new SinglyLinkedList();
  myList.push("111");
  myList.push("222");
  myList.push("333");
  console.log(myList);
```

Output:

```
SinglyLinkedList {
  length: 3,
  head: Node { val: '111', next: Node { val: '222', next: [Node] } },
  tail: Node { val: '333', next: null } }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does each `next` of a `head` gets assigned a new node if we say this.tail.next = newNode? Where is the relation between head and tail and how by saying this.tail.next = newNode we get access to the head property of the list?

Lets go back to the empty list. The first time a node is added, we get into the `if` block, where both `head` and `tail` will reference the *same* new node. This means that from that moment on, whatever you mutate in `tail` will be mutating `head`, since they refer to the same object.

Now a second `push` is executed and we get in the `else` block. There we assign the new node to the `next` property of `tail`. But since this is the same object that `head` refers to, we actually set `head.next` here! This only happens with the second `push`, because right after this assignment, `tail` is assigned a new reference (`next`) so from then on `head` and `tail` refer to different nodes.

Graphically:

After `push('111')`:

```
head
 ↓
111
 ↑
tail
```

When `push('222')`, after `this.tail.next = newNode;`:

```
head
 ↓
111 → 222
 ↑
tail
```

...and after `this.tail = newNode;` during that same push:

```
head
 ↓
111 → 222
       ↑
     tail
```

When `push('333')`, after `this.tail.next = newNode;`:

```
head
 ↓
111 → 222 → 333
       ↑
     tail
```

...and after `this.tail = newNode;` during that same push:

```
head
 ↓
111 → 222 → 333
             ↑
           tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll give it a try in explaining why that is.

1. When you push the first time, both `head` and `tail` refers to the same node.
2. Then when you push the second time, `this.tail.next = newNode` adds the new node to both `head` and `tail`'s next property.
3. Then `this.tail = newNode` updates the `tail`'s node which leaves the `head`'s next to be the same as tail.

If you want to check step 2 above, comment out `this.tail = newNode` and push twice. You will see both `head` and `tail`'s next property is same.